# PHP IF Statement for Password/Login not executing as planned

Tags: php, if-statement, encryption, authentication, comparison

I'm building a simple login system, using the mCrypt PHP extension. I'm not sure if this is the best way to do it, but my code is below:

```
 <?php
session_start();
require_once('classes/Crypt.class.php');
date_default_timezone_set("America/New_York");
$_SESSION['loggedIn'] = false;
$encryption = new Crypt();

if (!empty($_POST['loginNow'])) {
    $dateCompleted = date("Y-m-d");
    $birthday = $_POST['birthdayYear'] . "-" . $_POST['birthdayMonth'] . "-" . $_POST['birthdayDay']; 

    //Connect to SQL
    $dbhandle = new PDO("mysql:host=mysql.domain.com;dbname=database", "admin", "pass");
    $dbhandle->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

    //prepare data for select
    $sql = "SELECT `email-address`,`password`,`iv` FROM `users` WHERE `email-address` = '" . $_POST['emailAddress'] . "';";
    $stmt = $dbhandle->prepare($sql);

    //Execute
    $stmt->execute();

    $row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_BOTH);   

    if ($row['email-address']) {

        $decryptPassword = $encryption->decrypt($row['password'],$row['iv']);

        if ("123" == "123") {

            $_SESSION['loggedIn'] = true;
            header("Location: profile.php");
            exit();

        } else {

            $_SESSION['loggedIn'] = false;
            header("Location: login.php?error=incorrectLogin");
            exit();

        }

    } else {

        $newEncrypted = $encryption->encrypt($_POST['password']);
        $newIV = substr($newEncrypted, 0, 32);
        $newCryptPassword = substr($newEncrypted, 32);

        //Put form results into an array
        $data = array($_POST['firstName'],$_POST['lastName'],$_POST['emailAddress'],$newCryptPassword,$newIV,$birthday,$dateCompleted);

        //prepare data for insert
        $stmt2 = $dbhandle->prepare("INSERT INTO users (`first-name`,`last-name`,`email-address`,`password`,`iv`,`birthday`,`date-completed`)
        values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)");

        //execute query
        $stmt2->execute($data);

        $_SESSION['loggedIn'] = true;
        header("Location: profile.php");
        exit();
    }
}
?>
```

Crypt Class:

```
    <?php

class Crypt
{ 
    private $secretKey;

    public function __construct() 
    {
        $this->secretKey = MD5('super secret key');
    }

    public function encrypt($data)
    {
        $m = mcrypt_module_open('rijndael-256', '', 'cbc', '');

        $ivSize = mcrypt_get_iv_size('rijndael-256', 'cbc');
        //Create the IV
        $iv = mcrypt_create_iv ($ivSize, MCRYPT_DEV_RANDOM);

        //Initialize the encrpytion
        mcrypt_generic_init ($m, $this->secretKey, $iv);

        //Encrypt the data
        $encryptedData = mcrypt_generic($m, $data);

        //Close mCrypt
        mcrypt_generic_deinit($m);
        mcrypt_module_close($m);

        return $iv.$encryptedData;

    }

    public function decrypt($data,$iv)
    {
        //Open the Cipher
        $m = mcrypt_module_open('rijndael-256', '', 'cbc', '');

        //Initialize the Decryption
        mcrypt_generic_init($m, $this->secretKey, $iv);

        //Decrypt the Password
        $decryptedData = mdecrypt_generic($m, $data);

        //Close mCrypt
        mcrypt_generic_deinit($m);
        mcrypt_module_close($m);

        return $decryptedData;
    }
}

?>
```

In the If Statement that checks if the decrypted password equals the $_POST password variables value, it never executes to correct. Even though when I check the decrypted passwords value via echoing it, it's always the same as the $_POST password variables value.

I thought this may be because it's not a string, even though I'm using the "==" comparison operator as opposed to "===", so I cast the decrypted password to a string. Still same results.

I made some changes based on comments. Still doesn't work. I changed the if statement to ask if 123 = 123, still doesn't work. I must be doing something wrong. This is what is happening now:

```
$decryptPassword
```

123

```
$_POST['password']
```

123

```
gettype($decryptPassword)
```

string

```
gettype($_POST['password']
```

string

```
$decryptPassword == $_POST['password']
```

bool(false)

Comment: Just a few sidenotes: Both your form elements contain a name attribute and no typos/lettercase issues? You also need `session_start();` loaded *inside all pages* using sessions, and you should add `exit;` after each header.

Comment: BTW, the check for `($row['email-address'] == $_POST['emailAddress'])`, despite it’s not working for some reason, is **absolutely useless** since you have already selected the row from database, which is either **empty**, or has the `email-address` exactly equal to `_POST` value (see your query against database.)

Comment: @Fred-ii- Thanks for the comment, what do you mean 'name attribute' in my form elements? And my mistake with the `session_start();`, I didn't copy/paste the whole script, must have missed it. I'll add it now to the op. The `exit;` thing I wasn't aware of, so thanks for that.

Comment: You're welcome. `name="password"` and `name="emailAddress"` - Nota: `emailAddress` is not the same as `emailaddress`

Comment: @mudasobwa Hi, that's not the if statement that's having the problem. Although I understand what you're saying, in that it's useless because the query is already eliminating anything but the email being entered from being used. I suppose I can remove it altogether. Thanks.

Comment: @Fred-ii- Yes, as far as I know there's no typo issues occurring. But do you recommend a better process for naming my form elements?

Comment: That's the standard method. If you want to use something *out of the box*, have a look at http://daveismyname.com/login-and-registration-system-with-php-bp it uses PDO with prepared statements and the `password_hash()` function. The whole codes are in there, you don't need to "download" it.

Comment: So I changed the if statement to `if ("123" == "123") {
             
            $_SESSION['loggedIn'] = true;
            header("Location: profile.php");
            exit();
             
        } else {
             
            $_SESSION['loggedIn'] = false;
            header("Location: login.php?error=incorrectLogin");
            exit();
               
        }`, and it still doesn't work. I don't understand.

Comment: Concatenating the iv and encrypted password to get them out of the method is messy. PHP allows call by reference and can return array values - both of which makes the unnecessary. Not to mention support for crypt()

Comment: ....and storing passwords using reversible encryption is insecure.

Comment: ...and did you check that the IV was 32 chars? And is your column typed/sized to hold (escaped) binary?